# is SpEL supported in import statements?

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I would like to import different resource files based on some condition. Is this possible?

These don't work:

```
<import resource="#{ systemProperties['foo'] }.xml" /> 

<import resource="#{ T(my.testpkg).getValue() }.xml" />
```

Comment: If you're on Spring 3.1 or higher, you should probably use [*bean definition profiles*](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/) for this sort of thing if you can. I think `<import>`s are resolved fairly early, before the bean graph is constructed.

Comment: Well, placeholders ${...} seem to work in import statements, this would be a useful feature to have.

Comment: Those placeholders are still somewhat special-cased: http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/. Their values have to be available *before* the parsing. (Or before some other step in processing the bean definitions, I'm not that familiar with Spring internals.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpEL is supported, but Spring resolves the import statement very early on.

When spring is resolving import statements, property placeholders have not yet been resolved.

For example:

Define the following properties:

```
import.fileName=${blah}
blah=properties.props
```

We can then use the 'import.fileName' property as a parameter to the import

```
<import resource="${import.fileName}" />
```

This resolves to:

```
<import resource="${blah}" />
```

And presumably the resource '${blah}' does not exist.

That being said, you can use properties to resolve import file names.